# Problema no Formulário Select Multiple

Tags: php, formulário

Estou com problema em receber múltiplas escolhas e inserir no MySQL

Eu criei essa sequencia de script mas

```
<form method="post" action="01maxtestes.php">
<select name="padroes" size="10" multiple>

<?
    do  
      {

?>
        <option value="<? echo $MAXI_pad_select['PAD_ID']; ?>"><? echo $MAXI_pad_select['PAD_NUM_CERTIFICADO']; ?> - <? echo $MAXI_pad_select['PAD_IDENTI']; ?> - <? if($MAXI_pad_select['PAD_STATUS_VALIDA'] == 0){ echo "<strong>(VALIDO) </strong>"; }elseif($MAXI_pad_select['PAD_STATUS_VALIDA'] == 1){ echo "(H&Aacute; VENCER)"; }else{ echo "(VENCIDO)"; } ?></option>

<? }while($MAXI_pad_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($MAXI_pad_select_query));
?>

</select>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancelar" />
</form>
```

Ai ao enviar ele recebe apenas um numero através disso

```
$padroes_testesss = $_POST['padroes'];
```

só que se eu selecionar mais que um ele volta apenas a ultima informação selecionado. só que quero que volta 1 ou mais informações selecionado na lista vinculando ao um Insert Into de outra tabela.

alguem pode me dar uma força?

estou usando PHP 5,4.

Answer (score 0):

O name do seu select tem que ser padroes[]

`<select name="padroes[]" size="10" multiple>`

Dessa forma é enviado um array dos valores selecionados.

Para recuperar esses valores e inserir no DB faça assim:

```
if (isset($_POST["padroes"])) {
    $optionArray = $_POST["padroes"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($optionArray); $i++) {
        $todos=$todos.",".$optionArray[$i];
    }
}

$todos=substr($todos, 0, -1);
$aDest = explode(",", $todos);

("Insert into TABELA (coluna1,coluna2,coluna3 .......) 
  values ('".$aDest[0]."','".$aDest[1]."','".$aDest[2]."',.......
```